# Installation of dll's into GAC

Tags: c#, dll

I would like to have a smooth and efficient installation of the solution, but what I "inherited" is very far from that, and the guy who programmed most of it has left the company.

At present I am trying to install it on a test-server, and not all the dll's land in the correct places after the installation.

Firstly, if I use log4net in a project, then I need the log4net.dll in the folder after the installation (I guess). How do I get the log4net.dll to be copied with the project dll?

Secondly, Project A expects Project C's dll to be in the GAC or so it seems when I debug in Visual Studio and check where the modules are loaded from.
I also see that this is entered in the post build event commandline of Project A:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\GacUtil.exe"  -i "$(TargetPath)"
>   copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Program Files\MySolution\bin"

So how do I get Project C's dll into the GAC by way of the installation? I get an error on the Test Server because it can't load C.dll.

**UPDATE WITH MORE DETAIL**

After the solution has been installed with Windows Installer, a few folders are created in the parent folder such as Apps, bin, Engines, Service etc.

In the Apps folder, I have A.exe, which is looking for C.dll. However, C.dll lands up in the bin folder. As mentioned above, during execution of A.exe, it actually loads the modules of C.dll from the GAC (and on my laptop, those files *are* in the GAC because of the post-build event command line specified in the properties of Project C, but not in the GAC of the Test Server to which I am trying to install this solution).

So yes, I assume I could run something like this:

```
gacutil -i C.dll
```

after the installation, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: What installation technology are you using?  You shouldn't need to add the C libraries to the GAC, the GAC is for .Net assemblies only.  Why can you just not execute from the folder where everything is copied?

Comment: He appears to be referring to "Project C", not a project written in C.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @mageos, I am not using C libraries but writing C# code. I just called one of the projects, "Project C" as an example.

Comment: @mageos, I am using Windows Installer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your question relating to the GAC, and ensuring DLLs are copied.

**GAC**

Check out this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN on how to install into the GAC. The key thing is it must be strongly named or it will fail.

**DDLs**

Depending on how you are referencing Log4Net, there are a few ways to do this.

- If you can add a reference in your project, make sure the property CopyLocal is set to true
- If you just have the file locally, you can add it to a sub folder of your project with a symbolic link (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306234), and then set the CopyToOutputDirectory property.

Hopefully these help you along.

Comment: I actually had looked at the MSDN link, but didn't like having to do things after the installation. The note says _Gacutil.exe is only for development purposes and should not be used to install production assemblies into the global assembly cache._
I also used the symbolic link method in many projects of the solution to link to the external log4net file that I use for configuration, so that I only need one copy of the file. Good links though.

Comment: The link also shows how to install using Windows Installer for your deployments to customers. This is done using the "InstallShield Limited Edition Project", which is a free (requires registration) add-on. Pretty simple and straight forward UIs.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for!
Select the Setup project, then go to the menu "View" -> Editor -> File System.
It seems you can specify where the dlls must go, and what should be copied to the GAC during installation.